# Prove that there is a positive number $\delta$ such that the sum of the series is nonzero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Let $a, c_0, c_1,\ldots \in\mathbb{R}$ with at least one of $c_0,
>  c_1,\ldots$ nonzero. Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n (x-a)^n$ be a power
>   series with radius of covnergence $r>0$. Prove that there exists a
>   positive number $\delta$ smaller than $r$ such that the sum of the
>   series is nonzero for each $x$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

I have troubles with proving this fact. Somehow I feel that it can be proved using the fact that power series converges locally uniformly inside its area of convergence and manipulating a standard $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition.

Am I right? If no, could you post some hint?

Comment: I would look at the least $n$ such that $c_n\not=0$ ... though I need to think of the details, and whether the other $c_n$ growing fast might be relevant ... but you should be able to use continuity of the sum near $x=a$, so doesn't that solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $c_n(x-a)^n\to0$ if $|x-a|<r$, you have $c_n|x-a|^n<M2^{-n}$ if $|x-a|<r/2$.
With Mirko's least $m$ with $c_m\neq0$, take out the factor $(x-a)^m$, or else assume $c_0\neq0$.
You want an $\alpha$ with $M2^{-n}\alpha^n<c_02^{-n}$, so $\alpha=c_0/M$, and now the series stays away from 0 if $|x-a|<r\alpha/2$.

Comment: You used the fact that convergent sequence is bounded, right?

Comment: Yes, I skipped that step.

Comment: Could you explain why I want $M2^{-n}\alpha^n<c_02^{-n}$? Thank you.

Comment: Just as $r/2$ keeps $c_n|x-a|^n<M2^{-n}$, in the same way $r\alpha/2$ keeps $c_n|x-a|^n<M2^{-n}\alpha^n$.  If we keep that less than $c_02^{-n}$, the sum of all the terms after $c_0$ can never get back down to zero; the sum is more than $c_0-c_0/2-c_0/4-c_0/8...$

Comment: Very clever! I'm impressed! I wish I was so smart. Thank you!